# I have a problem with finding the trace to a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $T$ be a matrix of which I know its characteristic values, how can I find $\operatorname{Tr}(T-I)^{-1}$?

I know that the sum of the characteristic values is the trace, but I'm having a problem as I can't understand how I can know the new characteristic values of the new matrix using the old characteristic values and the old matrix.

Comment: Do you mean $\text{trace}((T - I)^{-1})$?

Comment: Also:  I think you might mean characteristic *values*, not characteristic *vectors*.  Am I right?

Comment: yes. the invertible matrix of (T-I)

Comment: I learn in another language so translating is a bit tricky... I think I know both the vectors and the values (not sure if that is what you meant)

Comment: If $Tv = \lambda v$, we usually say (in English) that $v$ is the *characteristic vector* corresponding to the *characteristic value* $\lambda$.

Comment: aha then I mean I know the characteristic values. thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if you know all of the eigenvalues (characteristic values) of $T$ then you also know the eigenvalues of $T-I$. Now you need two facts: one, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $S^{-1}$ if and only if $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $S$, and two, the trace of an operator is the sum of its eigenvalues.

Comment: can I say that if λ is a eigenvalue of T so λ-1 is an eigenvalue of T-I, then considering that the number of times λ-1 appears in T-1 is equal to the algebraic multiplicity of the old matrix, find the eigenvalue of T-1 using that then the trace of the matrix is 1/λ (because it's an invertible matrix).
is that how this question is solved?

Comment: Yep, pretty much! Once you have the eigenvalues of $T-I$ and their multiplicities, you simply invert them and add them (with the corresponding multiplicities, of course).

Comment: YES!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! 
If I pass my exam I'm getting you a new car lol.